# Add a new HashSet to a previous HashSet, "CHANGING" the previous HashSet and continue doing so until certain condition has been met

Tags: java, hashset

I know that if you have two `HashSet` the you can create a third one adding the two.However, for my purpose I need to change my previous `HashSet`, look for certain condition , and then if not met then change the set again.My purpose is that that I will give an input, say number `456`, and look for digits(1 through 9, including 0).If I'm unable to find size 10 for the `HashSet` then I will multiply the number with 2 , and do the same.So I'll get `912`; the size is 6 now(and I need to get all digits 1-9 & 0, i.e., size 10).Now I will multiply it by 3 and I get `2736` , the size is now 7.I keep doing so until I get size 10.At the time I get size 10, I will complete the loop and return the last number that concluded the loop, following the incremental multiplication rule.My approach is as follows.It has errors so won't run but it represents my understanding as of now.

```
 public long digitProcessSystem(long N) {
  // changing the passed in number into String 
  String number = Long.toString(N);
 //splitting the String so that I can investigate each digit
  String[] arr = number.split("");
// Storing the digits(which are Strings now) into HashSet
  Set<String> input = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
// Count starts for incremental purpose later.
  count =1;
 //When I get all digits; 1-9, & 0, I need to return the last number that concluded the condition
     while (input.size() == 10) {
         return N;
     }
// The compiler telling me to delete the else but as a new Java user so far my understanding is that I can use `else` with `while`loops.Correct me if I'm missing something.
     else {
          // Increment starts following the rule; N*1, N*2,N*3,...till size is 10
          N = N*count;
         // doing everything over
          String numberN = Long.toString(N);
          String[] arr1 = number.split("");
         // need to change the previous `input`so that the new updated `HashSet` gets passed in the while loop to look for size 10.This is error because I'm using same name `input`. But I don't want to create a new `set` , I need to update the previous `set` which I don't know how.
          Set<String> input = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
       // increments count  
       count++;

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#clear%28%29) `input` and add the new values. Something like

```
// Set<String> input = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
input.clear();
input.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr1));
```

**and**

```
while (input.size() == 10) {
```

should be

```
if (input.size() == 10) {
```

Or your `else` isn't tied to an `if`.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error on else .It's saying to delete the token.Why?@Elliott

Comment: Presumably, that `while` should have been an `if`.

Comment: But I want to loop through until I get the condition.@ Elliott

Comment: Your current loop body is a `return`, which means that condition will immediately terminate the loop.

Comment: Or maybe I can use a do-while loop.